# Firebase Error: Incompatible Android SDK

Tags: android, firebase

I'm getting this error, but I'm not sure what I did wrong. I made sure I updated everything according to the instructions on the firebase website. Is this a compatibility error?

```
09-22 13:12:51.158 18083-18110/com.pingus.vent W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 10298480
```

Gradle Files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pingus.vent"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libraries', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the same version for all Firebase services and Google play services as well, for example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
```

I used to use different versions for google play services and firebase services and got crashes.

Comment: true... I had the same problem and fixed that way